# Two equations on a line and A++

Tags: labels

I have an accepted paper in a journal. The paper contains an equation with two labels. We have typeset the paper using the journal's style files and it all looked perfect. We can reference both labels, click on any one of them, and we will be taken to the displayed equation.

But now the copyeditors are saying that if we have two equation labels on a line, then in the typeset **online** version we can only get a hyperlink to ONE of them. Either to the first label, or to the second label. The reason they give is that they are using A++ to typeset the paper. I am not sure what A++ is, but I do not understand why they could not give hyperlinks to both equation labels.

Here is an MWE. This works for me, but not for the journal.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, anchorcolor=red, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

    
 
\begin{document}
  
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
            \leqnomode
            \begin{equation}\label{primal}  
            \hspace{-3cm} 
            \begin{split}
            \max & \,\, c^\top x \\ %C \bullet X \\
            s.t.   & \,\,  A x \leq b  \\
            \end{split}\tag{P}
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{equation}\label{dual}
            \begin{split}
            \min  & \,\, b^T y   \\
            s.t. & \,\,  A^\top y = c \\
                   & y \geq 0    
                \end{split}\tag{D}
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    
    
\newpage    
    
    Reference \eqref{primal} here. Reference \eqref{dual} here. 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since your code works for you, this seems like a question about the journal, not about TeX.  (I'm also not sure that the MWE is really Minimal ….)

Comment: it works for the journal _in tex_ but they can not convert it, to the program they use for generating web pages. basically you need to do what they say if you want them to publish it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the journal's editorial staff has informed you that they cannot or will not pursue your preferred way of displaying the primal and dual formulations of a problem, you have no meaningful alternative choice but to come up with a different way of displaying the material.

One such way might consist of placing the systems of equations in a two-column table. For instance,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false, colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Primal and dual formulations of a problem} \label{tab:p_d}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} c@{\qquad\qquad}c @{}}
Primal & Dual \\
\midrule
$\begin{aligned}[t]
   \max\quad         &c^\top\! x \\
   \text{s.t.}\quad  &Ax\le b  
\end{aligned}$ & 
$\begin{aligned}[t]
   \min \quad       &b^\top\! y     \\
   \text{s.t.}\quad &A^\top\! y = c \\
                    &y\ge 0    
\end{aligned}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

As is shown in the left-hand column of \autoref{tab:p_d}, \dots

\end{document}
```